# jQuery .always() seems to fire before $.get() request is actually complete

Tags: ajax, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-callback

This is likely a misunderstanding on my part of how AJAX functions, but I have a situation where a `$.get` callback (`.always()`) is being called before the GET request actually finishes. At least, that's what it looks like.

**The Code**

```
var apiRequest  = 'some/url/';

// fetch list of video embed codes
$.get( apiRequest, function( embed_codes ) {

    // added this per Explosion Pills' answer
    var jqxhrs = [];

    // for each embed code, get video details (name, duration, etc.)
    for ( var i = 0; i < embed_codes.length; i++ ) {
        var videoDetailsRequest = '/v2/assets/' + embed_codes[i];
        //..declare vars..

        // fetch video details
        var jqxhr = $.get( videoDetailsRequest, function( video ) {
            // build playlist entry for each video
            playlistItem = '<li><h3>' + video.name + '</h3><p>' + video.description + '</p></li>';

            // create object of video HTML, with key = "video name" for sorting later
            videoArray[video.name] = playlistItem;
        }, 'jsonp' )

        // added this per Explosion Pills' answer
        jqxhrs.push( jqxhr );
    }

    // updated from jqxhr.always( function() {
    $.when( jqxhrs ).always( function() {
        // create array of keys
        for ( k in videoArray ) {
            if ( videoArray.hasOwnProperty( k ) ) { keys.push( k ); }
        }

        // append alphabetized list of videos to the page...
    });
}, 'jsonp' );
```

**What the Code Does**

Essentially, the code does this: loop through a list of video embed codes. For each iteration of the `for` loop, fetch details about each video and push those details into a multidimensional array. Once done fetching all videos, call the `.always()` callback, which sorts the videos into an alphabetized playlist and appends to the page.

**The Problem**

The `.always()` callback *sometimes* gets called before all of the videos have been fetched. There are 9 videos in the playlist, but sometimes only 6 or 7 are returned before the callback is fired, which means my playlist is a bit short. I have tested this by alert()ing the number of keys and using the console. What I've seen is that 6-7 videos will return, *then* the `alert()` in the callback fires, *then* the remaining videos are returned.

**MY QUESTION:**

Why is this happening? I thought the `.always()` callback fired *after* the AJAX request was complete. Doesn't this mean that all of the videos should be returned *before* the callback is fired? I suspect it has to do with the "A" in AJAX, but I thought the purpose of the `always()` callback was to account for this. Anything to help me understand is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have set this up, the `.always` callback will fire as soon as the *last* ajax request in the loop completes.  This can happen out of order with respect to the others.  I can't tell if you want it to fire when all requests in the loop have completed or when the outer request has completed.

For the outer request, it's easy.  Just chain a call to `.always` (or `.done`, I believe they are the same and the latter is preferred).

If you want it to complete when all the other ajax requests are completed, you can use `$.when`, which checks when *all* deferred objects are complete:

```
var jqxhrs = [];
   ...for loop...
   var jqxhr = $.get( videoDetailsRequest
   ...
   }, 'jsonp');
   jqxhrs.push(jqxhr);
...
$.when.apply(undefined, jqxhrs).always(function () { /* your intended callback */
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `.pipe`:

```
//Create initial deferred object
var jqxhr = $.Deferred();
   ...for loop...
   jqxhr = jqxhr.pipe($.get(...
jqxhr.always(function () { /* callback */
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't have luck with .pipe() but the `$.when()` is _almost_ there. When I view the console log, the `videoArray` inside the callback appears first, already sorted, _then_ the console logs each individual video in the `for` loop. Whaaat? For whatever reason, going this route prevents the `for` loop in the callback from executing, so I never get a `keys` array, which means I can't build my playlist. Any idea why that is? I updated my answer to include the code that builds the playlist.

Comment: @Ryan it's possible that `$.when` doesn't like an array as arguments, so try `$.when.apply(undefined, jqxhrs)` (this will call the `$.when` method, but instead of passing an an array it will work as if it calls `$.when(jqxhrs[0], jqxhrs[1]...)`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Just so I understand, do I have to do all this additional stuff because I'm making an AJAX call inside a `for` loop (which is itself inside another `$.get()` request)? Under normal circumstances the `.always()` callback should be fired after the AJAX request completes, right?

Comment: @Ryan typically yes -- it's because you are using multiple ajax calls and you need to wait until *all* of them are done.  The outer ajax call can still complete before any or all of the inner ones do.

Comment: Explosion, answer should be edited to reflect the `$.when.apply(...)` advice offered in a comment.